# Database Design for updatable sequential records

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am working on creating a data model for storing data related to production tracking.  I work for an engineering firm that models and analyzes data for our clients.  There are several steps in the process and the process is constantly updating.

I am trying to model the processes and include parent processes and sequential order of processes.

For example:

```
Process Table
---------------------
ProcessID - uniqueidentifier
ProcessName - varchar
ProcessDescription - varchar
...

ProcessOrder Table
---------------------
ProcessID - uniqueidentifier FK - Process
ParentProcessID - uniqueidentifier FK - Process
ProcessOrder - int
...
```

The `ProcessOrder` column in the `ProcessOrder` Table would simply store a number representing which sequential step in the parent process it represents.

For example, a modeling procedure has the following steps: create new empty model, name model, enter model parameters.  The `Process` Table would look like:

```
ProcessID | ProcessName | ProcessDescription
-------------------------------------------------
UUID1     | Modeling    | Create Model of Data
UUID2     | New Model   | create new empty model
UUID3     | Name Model  | name model
UUID4     | Parameters  | enter model parameters
```

The `ProcessOrder` Table would look like:

```
ProcessID | ParentProcessID | ProcessOrder
--------------------------------------------------
UUID2     | UUID1           | 1
UUID3     | UUID1           | 2
UUID4     | UUID1           | 3
```

The issue with this design is that when the workflow gets updated, the process order will change and I will need to update the `ProcessOrder` record for the process that changed and for all subsequent records with the same `ParentProcessID`.

Is there a better way to store this kind of data and maintain normalization?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is similar to the one I proposed at [Advise on database design for a project lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035357/advise-on-database-design-for-a-project-lifecycle/11264055#11264055)

The data above is for the different status values described in the previous example. So for each client project you have the following tables:

a) Client Project
- Clientid - reference to the client
- Status (FK to ProcessID) 
- Project Name, Description, date started

b) Status Changes - which tracks the changes from one status to another 
- projectid
- old status (FK to ProcessID) 
- new status (FK to ProcessID) 
- date changed
- notes (and other columns like approval etc)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is similar to why LinkedLists have better insert performance (given that you already have a reference to the node where you want to insert) vs. insertion in an ArrayList.

In an ArrayList when making an insertion you have to move all records to make room for the new insertion. This can take O(N) time assuming N records (imagine inserting at the beginning of the list).

In a LinkedList, you only need to update the nodes at the point you want to make the insertion. With the assumption above, this will take O(1) time as you only need to update the Prev node and Next node.

To setup a LinkedList structure in a database, instead of a ProcessOrder column, you would have two columns, PrevProcessID and NextProcessID.

The issue comes when selecting this. The naive approach would be to recursively self-join on the table. This will cause N joins.

Instead of using N joins, do not use any joins and select all Processes with the parent ID.

In code, have a Process object with the following fields:
ParentProcessID
ProcessID
PrevProcessID
NextProcessID

While reading in the records from the select, create these objects and store them in a HashTable with the ProcessID as the key. This will take O(N) time to loop through the select statement.

Now that the records are in a HashTable, you can easily move from one node to the next by looking up the NextProcessID (or PrevProcessID) in the table. Using the HashTable saves you from doing N joins and instead takes O(N) time to setup.

Comparing the two approaches

1) The current solution you have now. This is an ArrayList type solution (think of the ProcessOrder as an index). Insertions take O(N) time, while you save time on the read because you do not have to setup a HashTable. However if you are already looping through the returned records to setup entity objects, then this will be the same amount of setup time in the LinkedList solution.

2) My proposed solution. This is a LinkedList type solution. Insertions take O(1) time assuming you know where you want to insert. Setup time takes O(N) time.